# How can I install LVM2 without using using apt-get, yum, rpm, etc.?

Tags: software-installation, lvm, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install LVM2 on my Raspberry Pi. I can not use apt-get, yum, or rpm since none of these package managers are installed on my system.

I have downloaded `lvm2-2_02_70-1_fc14.tar.gz` from [here.](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/lvm2.git/) I unpacked the tar.gz file in /bin (is that the correct place to unpack?) but am not sure what to do next. There is no `./configure` that was unpacked for me to run. I have the following in the directory:

```
root@raspberrypi3:/bin/lvm2-2_02_70-1_fc14# ls
LVM2.2.02.70.tgz.asc                    lvm2-set-default-preferred_names.patch  mirrors                                 upstream
Makefile                                lvm2.spec                               sources                                 upstream-key.gpg
```

I need to be able to use the lvextend, vgdisplay, lvresize, and other LVM commands. **How can I finish installing LVM2?**

Comment: Is that package built for the Raspberry Pi architecture? If not, it won't be very useful. The source code is here: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=lvm2.git You'll also need to ensure the kernel has support for LVM2.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I am pretty new to this stuff. How can I check if the kernel has support for LVM2? Also I am not sure exactly what I am supposed to do with the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You downloaded the Fedora package source, which isn’t going to be much use to you.

You need to download a source archive from [the LVM2 project](http://www.sourceware.org/lvm2/), *e.g.* on [the kernel.org mirror](http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/lvm2/); currently the latest version is [`LVM2.2.02.171.tgz`](http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/lvm2/LVM2.2.02.171.tgz):

```
cd /tmp
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/lvm2/LVM2.2.02.171.tgz
```

Once you have that, extract it

```
tar xf LVM2.2.02.171.tgz
cd LVM2.2.02.171
```

and build it

```
./configure && make
```

and finally install it (as `root`)

```
make install
```

You might want to adjust options to `configure` depending on the tools you need and where you want the binaries to end up.

Comment: I am stuck on the `./configure && make` step. I am getting an error that says "no acceptable C compiler". From what I can tell I don't have a compiler installed yet. When I try to unpack the gcc.tar.gz file I have downloaded I get an error that says "No space left on device". I have a 8G SD card that looks like it is only using ~2G. From the the searching I have done it seems like the solution to this is to use LVM to make more usable space on my SD card. But I don't have LVM installed yet. Now I am back where I started...Any suggestions or should this be asked as a new question?

Comment: It sounds like you’d be better off installing a Raspberry Pi distribution (with packages) instead of trying to build stuff from source...